# How do you prevent deadlock in an OpenCL semaphore?

Tags: opencl, concurrent-programming

I am following [this](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=113&Itemid=168) tutorial which is great all the way through except the very last example on how to create a semaphore isn't working for me. The logic is fairly simple but I cannot figure out why this kernel results in an infinite loop.

**myKernel.cl**

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
void GetSemaphor(__global int * semaphor, __global int * data) {
   int occupied = atom_xchg(semaphor, 1);
   int realityCheck = 0;
   while(occupied == 1 && realityCheck++ < 100000)
        occupied = atom_xchg(semaphor, 1);
}

void ReleaseSemaphor(__global int * semaphor)
{
   int prevVal = atom_xchg(semaphor, 0);
}

__kernel void myKernel(__global int* data, __global int* semaphor)
{
    // semaphor[0] is set to 0 on the host.
    GetSemaphor(&semaphor[0], data);
    data[0]++;
    ReleaseSemaphor(&semaphor[0]);
}
```

This is with:

OpenCL 1.2

FULL_PROFILE

on a Quadro NVS 290 that has

*cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial you reffer is wrong and will never work on GPU devices. Due to HW arquitecture.

Any kind of sync mechanism that blocks a workitem inside a workgroup will simply not work. Since the blocking state will affect the whole workgroup, producing an infinite loop.

You can only do these kind of thing with a workgroup size of 1. Or across workgroups.

Comment: Agreed. The issue is that the first work item gets the semaphore, and then none of the rest of the work items can proceed, except that in most architectures a number of work items are tied together into a warp or wavefront and must proceed in lock-step, so by blocking the other work items you've deadlocked the entire warp/wavefront, which deadlocks the work group, which deadlocks your kernel.